# How do I set the output format for django rest framework datefield

Tags: django-rest-framework, datefield

I have the following very simple serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class EmailSendSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField(format='%B')
```

My understanding of the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datefield
is that the validated date returned by the serializer should be the full name of the month (as specified by %B), but I'm getting a normal date object.

I can find lots of SO references to changing the input_format of the datefield but nothing that refers to the output date.

e.g with an input to the serializer of date= {str} '2020-12-25' I would expect a result of "December" but I get {date} 2020-12-25.

How do I correctly use the format parameter to return the date format I want?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the data you are using with the serializer?

Comment: I tried to re-create the problem, but I got the correct answer. here is my [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGmqX.png)

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check my data but I certainly think it looks like your example

Comment: Ok so I found the issue. s.validated_data.date = "2020-12-25" BUT s.data.date="December". I was expecting to see the formatted date under the validated_data property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems formatted data will be saved as properties of the serializer.data property.

so using the serializer defined above:

```
data = {"date":"2020-12-25"}
serializer = EmailSendSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid() # True
print(s.data.date) # December
print(s.validated_data.date) # "2020-12-25"
```